# Canvas element causes incorrect rendering when used more than once or in a loop - PDFMake

Tags: node.js, pdfmake

I'm trying to generate multiple PDFs server side using [PDFMake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake). Each PDF has a certain section that's constant across all PDFs to be generated, `general`. That `general` section is then separated by a `line` and then the information specific to that document is loaded in beneath it.

This works great on the first PDF. On the second, however, the layout breaks. How can I fix this?

First PDF:
[image]

Second PDF:
[image]

```
 "use strict";
  const fs = require("fs");
  const PdfPrinter = require("pdfmake");

  const fonts = {
    Helvetica: {
      normal: "Helvetica",
      bold: "Helvetica-Bold",
      italics: "Helvetica-Oblique",
      bolditalics: "Helvetica-BoldOblique",
    },
  };

  const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);

  const general = [{ text: "This is general text" }];

  const first = [{ text: "This is the text for the first pdf" }];

  const second = [{ text: "This is the text for the second pdf" }];

  const line = [{canvas: [{ type: 'line', x1: 0, y1: 5, x2: 595-2*40, y2: 5, lineWidth: 2 }],margin: [ 0, 10, 0, 10 ]},];


  let docDefinition = {
    pageSize: "letter",
    defaultStyle: {
      font: "Helvetica"
    }
  };

  docDefinition.content = [general,line,first];
  let pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
  pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('one.pdf'));
  pdfDoc.end();


  docDefinition.content = [general,line,second];
  pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
  pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('two.pdf'));
  pdfDoc.end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I asked a question on the [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/2123) and the response was:

> One `docDefinition` variable can be used only once to generate PDF.

While that may be true I did find an adequate workaround by using a table with just the headerLine. This isn't my idea but I can't remember where I got it from.

```
function line() {
  //Usually one would use a canvas to draw the line
  //{canvas: [{ type: 'line', x1: 0, y1: 5, x2: 595-2*40, y2: 5, lineWidth: 2 }],margin: [ 0, 10, 0, 0 ]},
  //For some reason, that's not working and the layout just breaks
    return {
      table : {
        headerRows : 1,
        widths: ['100%'],
        body : [
                [''],
                ['']
                ]
        },
        layout : 'headerLineOnly'
    }
}
```

Then you use `line()` anywhere in your `docDefinition` that you need a line.

```
"use strict";
  const fs = require("fs");
  const PdfPrinter = require("pdfmake");

  const fonts = {
    Helvetica: {
      normal: "Helvetica",
      bold: "Helvetica-Bold",
      italics: "Helvetica-Oblique",
      bolditalics: "Helvetica-BoldOblique",
    },
  };

  const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);

  const general = [{ text: "This is general text" }];

  const first = [{ text: "This is the text for the first pdf" }];

  const second = [{ text: "This is the text for the second pdf" }];



  let docDefinition = {
    pageSize: "letter",
    defaultStyle: {
      font: "Helvetica"
    }
  };

  docDefinition.content = [general,line(),first];
  let pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
  pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('one.pdf'));
  pdfDoc.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a long time, but in the interest of helping others -- an easy way to fix this is to make your canvas return new objects. For instance I had:

```
report.canvas.titleArt = {}
```

If you change that static object to a function that returns an object, it seems to work fine:

```
report.canvas.titleArt = function() {
    return {};
}
```